# Twilio Twilio/Rest/Calls.php error

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-click-to-call

whenever I am trying to make a conference call it says application error and I get an error in error log as :

PHP Warning:  strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/aan/public_html/twilio/twilio-php-4.11.0/Services/Twilio/Rest/Calls.php on line 16

Here is the code

```
<?php

require("twilio-php-4.11.0/Services/Twilio/Twiml.php");

    if($_REQUEST['Digits'] != '1') {
        header("Location: twiml.php");
        die;
    }

   $MODERATOR = $_GET['phone'];

$response = new Services_Twilio_Twiml();


$dial = $response->dial($MODERATOR);
  $dial->conference('My conference', array(
                'startConferenceOnEnter' => True
                ));
```

I have already made the call and gathered the digit , but when I dial second number and try to make these as conference I get this error

Comment: Is that the complete PHP file?  Seems like that error would only happen if the `create` function was getting called somewhere:  https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php/blob/4.11.0/Services/Twilio/Rest/Calls.php#L26

Comment: @DevinRader Thanks for answering. This issue is resolved.

Comment: Hey Stacy, glad you resolved the issue! Would you mind posting your fix in answer section so others can benefit and you can get upvotes :)

Comment: @MeganSpeir I changed it to  .....  header("content-type: text/xml");
    echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";
?>
<Response>
    <Dial><?php echo $phone ?></Dial>
</Response>

Answer (score 1):

I usually use TwiML for making a conference call, It's simple to implement.

```
$my_conference = "My Conference";
$statusCallbackUrl = "https://example.net/Welcome/conference_control"; // call back url    
<Response>
  <Dial> 
    <Conference beep="false" statusCallback="<?php echo $statusCallbackUrl; ?>" 
      statusCallbackEvent="start end join leave mute hold" endConferenceOnExit="true" 
      startConferenceOnEnter="true"> 
        <?php echo $my_conference; ?>
    </Conference>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

Hopefully, it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
header("content-type: text/xml"); 
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n"; 
?> 
<Response> 
 <Dial><?php echo $phone ?></Dial> 
</Response>
```

The snippet here was OP's fix for encountering an error using [twilio-php library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/php).